# How to change ReactiveVar behavior to run subscribtion even on equal set()?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I would like my ReactiveVar to react even when the set is the same as before?

In the documentation it says the ReactiveVar can take an optional equalsFunc that takes two arguments.

https://docs.meteor.com/api/reactive-var.html

```
let idToSeeIfExists = new ReactiveVar("",(old,new)=>{ return false });
```

I have put this function to always return false because I want my subscribtion to rerun even if it's the same value.

```
Template.admin.onCreated(function adminCreated() {
    this.autorun(() => {
        Meteor.subscribe('ensembles');
        Meteor.subscribe('objetsFindOne', idToSeeIfExists.get(), function () {
            if (idToSeeIfExists.get() != "")
                verifObjetCallback();
        });
    });
});
```

When I do idToSeeIfExists.set("1"); my subscribtion is called and all is well. But when I do it a second time it doesn't get called.

How can I achieve that? I thought the equalsFunc was exactly for that use case. I also put a breakpoint on the return false and it is indeed being called everytime I set it to 1 but my subscribtion doesn't react to the change.

I could write some code to contourn this use case but if it is possible with ReactiveVar I would rather do it using it.

Comment: Line 77 of [reactive-var.js](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/abd574f38008b45f5e2a6bc322b10bcdde44763a/packages/reactive-var/reactive-var.js) seems to be where the code actually does the check.  I don't see any reason that what you are doing shouldn't just "work".  I would start by putting a break on that line in your browser's Dev tools and seeing what happens.  Worse-case is you can overwrite/extend the set method.

Comment: Agree, _should_ work.